# Regular Expressions Variables

Tags: php, html, regex, laravel

I am using Sublime Text to replace some HTML inputs with Regular Expressions to make my work easier than replacing one by one.

I have several inputs where they don't have any defined ID and I want to assign them IDs dynamically according to their name.

I use this regex to find all the input fields:

`<input class="form-control" [a-z]{1,99}="[a-z]{1,30}" .[a-z="0]{1,20} name="([a-z_]{1,50})"`

Is there a way to do what I need using regular expressions? For example here are some lines of code:

```
<div class="row">
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Temporada</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" name="season" value="{{ old('season') }}">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Anual</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" name="annual" value="{{ old('annual') }}">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="form-group col-md">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Invierno</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="number" min="0" name="winter" value="{{ old('winter') }}">
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

So I want to change the `name="<somethingHere>` to `name="<somethingHere>" id="<somethingHere>"`. So, I won't have to modify the entire form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: from jquery you want to do that thing?

Comment: You can select `name="` then press `ctrl+d` to find all then replace as required. As only `name` is present you don't have to look for other attributes. You can just copy and add to new attributes.

Comment: i'm so confused by your syntax. for instance, shouldn't `[a-z]{1,99}="[a-z]{1,30}"` simply be `id="[a-z]{1,30}"` or even `data-[a-z]{1,99}="[a-z]{1,30}"`??? and what is the following this random string, `.[a-z="0]{1,20}`, doing in there??

Comment: also, you can easily accomplish this with JS, and i'm sure you can accomplish the same thing with vanilla PHP. what exactly are the dynamically generated values based on, what is determining them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regex Find-and-Replace:

Find what:

```
(<input[^>]+?name="([^"]*)")
```

Replace with:

```
$1 id="$2"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.